# Vim: Why can't I map to the <j> key?

Tags: vim

I saw this key bind in tips.txt:

```
:map <C-U> <C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y>
```

Which results in smooth scrolling up for **CTRL-U**. It only moves the viewport though, and I'd like to also move the cursor, so for scrolling down I tried:

```
:map <C-D> <C-E><j><C-E><j><C-E><j><C-E><j><C-E><j><C-E><j><C-E><j><C-E><j>
```

Since **CTRL-E** moves the viewport down and **j** moved the cursor down. This doesn't work however. When I press **CTRL-D** the viewport just hops one line down and the terminal beeps.

How do I map **CTRL+D** to scroll and move the cursor?

Comment: By the way, `<C-Y>` accepts count, meaning that you can write just `12<C-y>` instead of this nonsense. Second is that you should not ever use `*map`, you need just `noremap` here. [Explanation](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html).

Comment: @ZyX: I guess you didn't read the question. This way results in *smooth* scrolling. If I just repeat the commands the way you suggest, then the scrolling is instantaneous and disorienting.

Comment: Then you could use `:execute "noremap <C-u> ".repeat("<C-y>", 12)`. Though this is kinda hack and depends on the system and vim configuration. I don’t notice *any* difference in yakuake (konsole) or rxvt-unicode (urxvt) where (the former) I test all this stuff, either with or without `'lazyredraw'` set. I don’t notice it in `xterm` with `'lazyredraw'`. The only condition where I do notice is `xterm` without `'lazyredraw'`. And urxvt without, but only if I look really hard (in yakuake it does not matter how hard I look). Though even in xterm w/o I can’t call your solution less disordering.

Comment: Thus the fact that your variant works means only that your terminal and/or system is slow. It depends on heaviness of syntax highlighting rules: if I disable syntax I overlook this fact in urxvt (not in xterm though).

Comment: @ZyX: this worked to achieve smooth scrolling in Vim in the Windows 8 CMD. Once I started using Gvim it became instantaneous again though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't have the angled brackets (`<`/`>`) around `j`.

Comment: See `:help key-notation`; it's only used for special key (combos).